# Error connecting to WCF Service c#

Tags: c#, json, ajax, wcf, soap

I'm developing a SOAP software for a customer. We are migrating to SOAP because we'll do a mobile app soon.

I alread did the .svc file and connects with IE. But, if I try to connect with Firefox, Opera, GC or any other browser, it says "Method not allowed".

I alread tried to insert a header on AJAX/JSON to allow 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. I also insert on server side, on the interface the webinvoke header, and nothing works.

This is my first question on stack overflow, so I do not know how asking works.

Thanks to all!

Header Code of AJAX/JSON:

```
function SendToService(urlSvc, objDTO) {

var bk = null;
var item = {
    info: objDTO
};

$.ajax({
    url: urlSvc,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:16587',
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        bk = msg.d;
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        bk = false;
    }
});

return bk;
```

};

Comment: *We are migrating to SOAP because we'll do a mobile app soon.* - this statement doesn't really make sense.

Comment: The mobile app will access the web service. The user can use via apk or Browser

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your method doesn't allow POST requests. Try allowing for POST on the destination method or test by changing your ajax request to GET instead. If the GET succeeds, you know where your problem is.

Comment: This should be a comment as it doesn't provide a solution to the question.